# Android Dalvik Emulator cannot connect to GPS

Tags: android, icons, gps, satellite

I am beginner in Android and I have a problem with GPS in the Dalvik Emulator.
I added hardware gps support on AVD and after booting I checked Use GPS Satellites in

```
Settings -> Location & Security -> Use GPS Satellites.
```

I enable **Use GPS Satellites** but there is no indication that GPS is turned on. There is no  satellite indicator at the top of the screen.

I tried to send coordinates to the emulator via DDMS (on a simple application) and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you requested location/location updates in your app? If you haven't, the GPS won't get enabled until some application requests location from it, even though it's turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending coordinates manually:

from DDMS view > Emulator Control Tab > any lat & any long > SEND

if your app is listening to changes, it should work